# Adding email and password input to a const in Jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So the code below allows me to add an email and password and when i hit submit it post it inside the box. This is great but I would like it to also add it to an object called "users" so every time I add an username and password. It creates a new use (ex. user1. user2) and inputes the email and password in it each users.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style>

            #userinfo {
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                color: black;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <form>

        <input id="userEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">

        <input id="userPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">

        <button id="sub-btn" name="submit" class="btnAction">Add User</button>

        </form>


        <div id="userinfo">

            <p></p>

        </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                  $('#sub-btn').click(function () {
                    const email = $('#userEmail').val();
                    const password = $('#userPassword').val();
                    const account = {
                      user1: [
                        email: '',
                        password: '',
                      ]
                    };

                    console.log(account);
                    event.preventDefault();
                    
                      if (email && password) {
                       // account.users.email.add(email); I know this isnt right but im guessing this is where the right code should go
                        $('#userinfo').html(email);
                        console.log(account);
                      }

                  })
                </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `.push()` your created `account` Object to your `users` Array:

```js
var users = []; // Empty array 

$('#sub-btn').click(function( event ) {

  event.preventDefault();

  const email =    $.trim($('#userEmail').val());
  const password = $.trim($('#userPassword').val());
  
  // Prevent empty
  if (!email && !password) return alert("Enter Email and Password");
  
  // create account
  var account = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
  };
  
  // Push account to users
  users.push(account)

  // Test
  console.clear();
  console.log("account: %o is added to users: %o", account, users);

  // Insert into table
  $('#userinfo').prepend("<tr><td>"+ email +"</td><td>"+ password +"</td></tr>");

  // Clear old values
  $("#userEmail, #userPassword").val("");

});
```

```css
#userinfo td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="userEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">
  <input id="userPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">
  <button id="sub-btn" name="submit" class="btnAction">Add User</button>
</form>
<table id="userinfo"></table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

So yeah, don't use `user1`, `user2` etc inside an object (like you did) - Arrays are the perfect use-case for that purpose.

Comment: This actually worked amazingly. never seen .trim be used which after looking it up... its amazing! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the structure of your JSON to be like below.

```
var data = {
        users: [
            { email: 'a@test.com', password: 'abc' },
            { email: 'b@test.com', password: '123' }
        ]
    };
```

Then then you can push to data to the array as shown below.

```
data.users.push({ email: 'c@test.com', password: 'def'});
```